# Python scraping script, avoid errors

Tags: python, twitter, beautifulsoup, urllib2, urllib

I have large script where I scrape tweets from twitter without API because it's restricted. This script really do the job, but in some cases comes to an error like:

```
URLError: <urlopen error EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:590)>
```

Or something like:

```
URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond>
```

Of course, I am using User Agent

```
request = urllib2.Request(url, headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.94 Safari/537.36"})
response = urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
```

So website will think that I am using some of these web browsers, the script really works and do the infinitely scroll, everything, but after some number of tweets comes to an error like these. Maybe twitter set me to the blacklist or something like that? I changed my IP, same is happening.. Or if the script change IP after 5 loops maybe, is it possible?

I am using these imports in my script:

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json, csv, urllib2, urllib, re
```

Comment: I think you just have connection issues. You can wrap the request in a `try…except` block and retry if it failed.

Comment: What version of Python are you using and is it a special distribution?